# Chinese to Chữ Nôm converter online

Tags: etymology, simplified-characters, old-chinese

Why it is very hard to find the Chữ Nôm for the very common Hanzi 有 ?
Maybe this Hanzi was not so used in the past ?
This looks very strange, and any light on it is welcome !

Comment: You should try a Vietnamese site for luck.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - it's like asking to convert the English letter A into the Swedish alphabet. 「有」 already exists in Vietnamese Hán-Nôm, what exactly are you looking for by "converting it to Chữ Nôm"?

Comment: When i was looking for Chữ Nôm of 有  and  打 (the name of my company : 打有 ) i succeeded to find Chữ Nôm of 打 :  đánh.  But strangely i was unable to find the Chữ Nôm for 有. The very interesting website https://chunom.org doesn't give any Chữ Nôm for this very common hanzi. More : on the other very interesting website http://www.nomfoundation.org/nom-project/tale-of-kieu/Glossary-of-characters-in-a-version-of-Kieu gives a very small frequency for  有 (hữu) in the well known "tale-of-kieu" and i still wonder why frequency is so different from the use in Chinese (有 is ninth in frequency).

Comment: @dROOOze  I am sorry, maybe something went wrong : i think we do not speak about the same thing. The content of this page :  www.thivien.net/Hồ-Chí-Minh/Nguyên-tiêu/poem-9nGoTWzYHnMiK0mDAEFGOA  may have misled me : Chữ Nôm is the first part (hanzis) or the second part which is not Vietnamese  ? I take the first part for usual hanzis, since they seem to not be written in an other way !  i'm puzzled :-)

Comment: **đánh** is the [Quốc ngữ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_alphabet) of 「打」 (not Chữ Nôm). On that page, **Nguyên tiêu** is the Quốc ngữ transliteration of the poem 「元宵」 (which is written in Classical Chinese), and the section under **Dịch nghĩa** (譯義, which means *translation*) is the Vietnamese translation of 「元宵」. There is no Chữ Nôm on that page.

Answer (score 1):

有 hữu isn't used in Vietnamese, which is why you don't see it on Chữ Nôm websites. It is only used in Literary Chinese texts (漢文; Hán văn; 文言文). "打有" can be transliterated into Vietnamese as "Đả Hữu". Đánh is the Nôm reading (喃) of 打, while đả is the Sino-Vietnamese reading (漢). It would still be written as 打有.